# Ubuntu UI and theme is changed when I logged out and logged in?

Tags: themes

I logged out of ubuntu and logged in after some time. I found that that ubuntu UI and theme all is changed to some strange UI and them. It is shown as below U

[image]

I am not sure how happened and how to fix it. I am using dual boot with windows 10 and ubuntu 17.10 Do somebody know why it can happen or how to fix it.

I want to use normal UI as :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is just another desktop environment. You can change it while logging in.
Logout from your Ubuntu, and in login screen you will see Ubuntu icon on top right corner of login modal.
Click on it and choose Ubuntu default.

If you want to determine which Desktop Environment you are in right now,

```
pgrep -l "gnome|kde|mate|cinnamon|xfce"
```

or

```
$DESKTOP_SESSION
```

Comment: Do accept the answer if it helped you fix the issue. It will help others too.